# Page_Init vs. Page_Load to read session data

Tags: c#, asp.net

This question might be ridiculous, sorry for that.

Which event is best for reading session data - `Page_Load` or `Page_Init` event?

Currently I am using `Page_Load` event for such tasks. But i have seen in [an article](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2008/11/detecting-session-timeout-and-redirect.html) to do in `Page_Init` event.

Thanks.

Update: http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2008/11/detecting-session-timeout-and-redirect.html

Comment: Could you share the article please?

Comment: I would work with the session data in the page_load event, as this event will be called with subsequest postbacks.

Comment: Page_init will also be called with subsequent postbacks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session is attached with your request while http request passes through ASP.NET pipeline. So before the page processing begins, you have your session with you. Session is stored on the server and is attached to your user request with the help of session id cookie. This cookie identifies each unique request and attaches session data(Session Module does this work).

I think you are confused with ViewState, because ViewState is stored and read in page life cycle (LoadViewState and SaveViewState event)

Also the article that you have pointed is for detecting new sesssions and time outs. It makes sense to do all the checking in Page_Int, so that response is sent as early as possible

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't matter, use the event where you need it. A `Session` variable is stored in server memory(by default), so it doesn't depend on the current page's lifecycle.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can access the the session data at any any stage of the page lifecycle. It does not affect it in any way. There is nothing like the 'best' or the 'worst'.

Answer (score 0):

Be more consistent. If your request need some kind of INFORMATION (no matter where you store it), then you should check the presence of INFORMATION before excuting the request.

If you store your information in sesssion than use:

Global.asax:Application_BeginRequest

this prevent you from copy-paste single requirement to multiple page.aspx